# How can I create a new HttpContext?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, httpcontext

```
public void getContent() {
    string VirtualPath = "~/Content.aspx";
    var page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath( VirtualPath, typeof( Page ) ) as IHttpHandler;
    page.ProcessRequest( HttpContext.Current );
}
```

I'm using that function to load the content from different files, but the "page.ProcessRequest( HttpContext.Current )" inserts the content at the current context, and what I need is the function to return the content of the specified file.

I wonder if there's a working way to create a new HttpContext, so that "page.ProcessRequest" don't insert anything into the current response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oded is correct as far as I know.  You can't easily create your own instance of the HttpContext.  However you can still achieve your goals thorugh other means.

Use a Server.Execute. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150027.aspx.

You can specify the HttpHandler to execute along with a TextWriter to dump the content into.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a new `HttpContext`, not without lots of work arounds.

It is one of the failings of ASP.NET and the BCL - makes web applications untestable (or at least very difficult to test without `HttpContext`.

I am not clear on your requirement `what I need is the function to return the content of the specified file` - can you please explain exactly what you mean by that?

Comment: Well i want to load/process interal .aspx files and get the html they return, but i don't want to do it via WebRequest :-/  So that i can store the content/html of those "modules" and re-use them without doing another request.

Comment: @Carlos - Do you mean you want to use them as templates?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Pex/Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) its includes a mocking framework that can mock almost any type or member, even if its sealed or static.
(it does this by using a custom test host)